# Any way to 'binge-cook'?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Cooking is great, but when you have 10-15 recipies to do in a row, it can get long fast.

Is there any way to do something like 1 apple + 1 sunshroom x 10 and Cook all of it at once instead of doing the cooking process 10 times?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No sadly, this is not possible. The only things you can cook in bulk are items that are cooked by leaving next to fire/in a hot place, such as Baked Apples and Seared Meat. You can simply drop as many as you'd like then pick them all up once they're done.